# Indecomposable quotient

Tags: representation-theory

Quotients of any indecomposable projective  module is still indecomposable.

I have feelings it is true since its quotient by the radical is simple but just couldn't come up with a rigorous argument. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your claim depends on the assumptions you are implicitly making. For example $\mathbb{Z}$ is projective and indecomposable but has indecomposable quotients. However you say that the quotient of a projective indecomposable module by its radical is simple, so I suppose you are working with finite dimensional algebras over some field or something similar where this is actually true?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply as it seemsed no one appeared interested in this question at first. Yes , you are correct.  I work mostly on the group algebra with finite group and some field k! Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ a finite dimensional $k$-algebra. Then indeed the quotient of an indecomposable projective module by its radical is simple.

Let $P$ be such a module and suppose that $P/N \cong M_1 \oplus M_2$ for some submodule $N \subseteq P$ and some nontrivial $A$-modules $M_1$ and $M_2$. Since $M_1$ and $M_2$ are finite dimensional, each of them has a simple quotient, say $S_1$ and $S_2$. Thus, there exists an epimorphism $\varphi: P \to S_1 \oplus S_2$ and since the image is semisimple we have to have $rad(P) \subseteq \ker(\varphi)$ (the quotient $M/rad(M)$ is the maximal semisimple quotient of $M$). However $P/rad(P)$ is simple, thus $rad(P)$ is maximal but $\ker(\varphi) \supseteq rad(P)$ is not since $P/\ker(\varphi)$ is not simple and this gives the desired contradiction and so $M_1$ and $M_2$ cannot both be nontrivial.